# How to check if an input contains only upper and lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes by onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How to check in this form if input contains only upper and lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes by onclick event?

```
<form id="domaincheck" class="form-inline ltr" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control center input-md" name="sld" id="sld" placeholder="pleade enter domain name" required>
    <select class="form-control ltr input-md input-group-addon" id="tld" name="tld" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="com" selected="">.com</option>
        <option value="net">.net</option>
        <option value="org">.org</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="get_whois()">check!</button>
</form>

<script>
function get_whois(){
    var sld = $('#sld').val();
    if (sld.length == 0) {
        alert('plase enter domain name!');
        return false;
    }
    if (sld.length <= 3) {
        alert('at least 4 chars');
        return false;
    } else {
        //do something
    }
}
<script>
```

Comment: You should look into [RegExp in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). Filter your input that way!

Comment: @LucaKiebel  how to use in this code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is probably the best way.

Use javascript [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with regex `/[0-9_a-zA-Z]+$/g` to test a string with regex.

Here is a great place to learn and test [your regex](http://regexr.com)

**JS**

```
function validate(val) {
     var re = /^[0-9_a-zA-Z]+$/g;
     return re.test(val); //validates regex on val and return true if passed.
}

function get_whois(){
var sld = $('#sld').val();
if (sld.length == 0) {
    alert('plase enter domain name!');
    return false;
}
if (sld.length <= 3) {
    alert('at least 4 chars');
    return false;
} else if(!validate(sld)){ // call validate function defined above here
    alert('Allowed A-Za-z0-9_ only.');
    return false; 
  }else{
       //do something 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for code, but not worked correctly and accept all chars. please check it here>> [link](https://codepen.io/jamallou/pen/qjBVqm)

Comment: @Mohammad J  updated  the code and regex please check.

Comment: Thanks. All done. also I found that the following regex  " /^[A-Za-z\-]+$/i " could be ok too and as I wont replaced underscore with dash.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I worked with jQuery validator and I wrote a simple password checker.

This is my function :

```
function(value) {
    return /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/.test(value) // allowed characters

         && /[a-z]/.test(value) // contains lowercase
         && /[A-Z]/.test(value) // contains UPPERCASE
         && /[0-9]/.test(value) // contains Number
}
```

The function returns `Boolean`